# Turn .obj files in to .mdl for Gmod

Tags: source-engine

want to import models that i made in to garrys mod but i cant figure out how to convert them in to .mdl files. I dont have any moding experience with the source engine. I tried to find a program to convert them but with no luck.
My models are textured (`.png` files for the textures and the `.mtl` for the mapsing)
Any wany to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the obj file to smd, and have your normal textures converted to vtf. There is a program to do this called OBJ2SMD. It turns your obj and png into smd and vtf by just dragging and dropping the model and texture into the program window. But it only lets you use ONE texture on the whole model. Here is the link:

http://bob.gneu.org/software-releases/obj-2-smd-converter/

After your model is converted to smd and vtf, find a model compiler. Then insert your model into your gmod game.